# Are glGetUniformLocation indices for arrays of uniforms guaranteed sequential except on GL ES?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

The documentation for GL|ES mentions [>here<](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml)

> Locations for sequential array indices are not required to be sequential.  The location for "a[ 1 ]" may or may not be equal to the location for "a[ 0 ]" + 1.

Is this true always on all OpenGL implementations or just GL|ES ?

Comment: This is the first I have _ever_ heard of this. Indeed, I looked at the GL 4.5 specification changes, and this language is new. Prior versions of the specification were worded in such a way that this (sequential locations) was guaranteed.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: can you point to one such guarantee? I did not find one. The only guarantees I can find are that if you have a location referencing an array or sub-arrayt, you can set the values of a sequential range in that (sub) array using just that starting location.

Comment: @derhass: Ahhhh. Yes, that is actually what I was referring to; I misinterpreted this question. You can take any uniform location in an array and write sequentially by using a `count` > **1**. You definitely cannot query the location of `x [y+1]` and expect it to be `x [y]` + 1.

Comment: This is especially true if the GLSL compiler determines a range of a uniform array is inactive. It's entirely possible that `x [y+1]` comes back **-1**, while `x [y]` has an actual location. _Locations for sequential array indices are not required to even exist._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [original GL_ARB_shader_objects extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_objects.txt) (where shader objects and uniforms were first introduced into the GL) contains the following statement:

> It is possible to
>       query the location ID of an element K in an array. It is possible to use
>       that location ID to load multiple values into an array starting at that
>       location K. However, it is not possible to take that location ID and add
>       an integer N to that location ID to advance to element K + N in that
>       array. The application will have to query the location ID of array
>       element K + N separately.

When shaders were added to core GL in version 2.0, this language was not adopted from the extension spec. **However, there never was a gaurantee that consecutive array elements would have consecutive uniform locations in any of the GL specs**, so you never could rely on it.